# Double cone with a specific aperture in MATLAB angle

Tags: matlab, math, geometry

I am trying to plot a double cone that has a specific aperture/apex angle (say theta) in MATLAB like the sketch below:

[image: Double-Cone]

My attempt:
A cone is described parametrically as:

F(s,t,u) = (u tan(s) cos(t),u tan(s) sin(t),u)

where s runs from 0 to theta (aperture 2*theta), t runs from 0 to 2*pi and u from 0 to h (height).

```
s = linspace(0,theta);
t = linspace(0,2*pi);
[S,T] = meshgrid(s,t);
X = tan(S).*cos(T);
Y = tan(S).*sin(T);
Z = tan(S);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

I wasn't sure how to add u to all this, so I simply did Z = tan(S). This does plot me a cone, but I'm not that sure on what I did here...

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried where is some code, equation or at least sketch? What is the real problem preventing you from success?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: I would use for  `a=<0,2*Pi>, h=<-H,+H>` something like: `z=h; r=abs(h)*tan(aperture_half_angle); x=r*cos(a); y=r*sin(a);` ... not a Matlab coder so there might be deviations like angle units ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more easier if you use the implicit form of the cone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).